# Is it possible to pass a report dataset as a method parameter to a custom assembly in SSRS 2008 or above?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

**TL;DR** In a SSRS 2008 report which uses a custom assembly to do some extra calculations can I pass an entire report dataset as a method parameter?

**Full story**

I have an SSRS report with 3 datasets, each returned from an SQL query.
(In case it makes a difference to my question they're currently shared datasets although I'm sure local would work too)

The largest and primary dataset is a list of tasks which may or may not have been completed. I have information in here such as the ID, status, create date/time, target resolution hours etc of each task.
This dataset is displayed in a tablix and is the focus of the report.

The remaining two datasets are not displayed and are for reference. One is a simple one column query which returns a list of holiday dates for the UK. The other is a small table which contains our exact business hours.

At the moment I'm able to loop through the rows in the tablix of tasks and pass multiple values from the current row to a method. This is useful if I want to do some calculations based on data found only in the current row. For example I could take the create date/time and the response target hours and the assembly would return a target date/time for the current task. Cool so far.

I want to do a more complicated version of this where I not only pass in the row data but the 2 other datasets to get my return value. This is because in reality the due date calculation is much more complex and must take into account changing business hours and holidays from the other 2 datasets.

Can I pass a dataset as a method parameter to an assembly? Something like:
`=Code.MyClass.MyMethod(val1, val2, dataset1, dataset2);`.

I've been unable to find much definitive information on this. Nearly all tutorials demonstrate what I'm already doing by processing single rows. I'm sure I had an MSDN article that hinted this was not possible but I've lost it (helpful I know). There's a [post on the Microsoft forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4a25529e-bd9d-47ea-9539-7756146f0829/passing-dataset-as-parameter-to-custom-assembly-in-ssrs-208-r2?forum=sqlreportingservices) where a moderator says it's not possible. The general lack of information and tutorials suggests it's not possible or I'm doing this in the wrong way.

Any suggestions?

(I have alternate solutions such as having the assembly fetch the other datasets or just writing something outside SSRS but I'm not pursuing those until I knnow whether it can be done this way).

Comment: Did you think about create another data region, call a function passing every row and store every row in a proper data structure collection or array? Once you have the rows stored in such data structure you can reference it from your functions.

Comment: I didn't think of that, but it sounds like it could work. Is it something you've tried yourself with success? I'll look at this while waiting for other views.

Comment: I've done that with small datasets but not sure about performance with huge datasets it could increase report processing time.

Comment: @Equalsk: You could use the LookupSet function to get back an array to pass into your method. Just use a fake ID to get back all records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An older topic on the MSDN forums [Iterate through rows of dataset in report's custom code](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a7d59224-0ee5-491e-883b-2e5fcb3edeab/iterate-through-rows-of-dataset-in-reports-custom-code?forum=sqlreportingservices) offers a more definitive answer as well as a potential solution to this problem.

Passing the DataSet as an object or collection is not a possibility because:

> A dataset in Reporting Services is not the same type of object as an ADO.Net dataset.  A report dataset is an internal object managed by the SSRS runtime (it's actually derived from a DataReader object) and not an XML structure containing datatables, etc. and cannot be passed into the report's custom code.
>
> The only way to effectively loop through the rows of a report dataset is to call a custom function or referenced method in a report data region expression.  Using this technique, it may be possible to pass all of the the row and field information into a code structure, array or collection.

The *hint* given in the above statement suggests passing row and field information into a code structure. A contributor to the linked MSDN topic, Migeul Catalao developed a workaround using such an approach.

A real-world scenario of it's usage with example code demonstrating Migeul Catalao's solution can be found [here](https://theway4ward.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/sql-reporting-services-and-working-days-across-datasets/).

Granted, it is still more of a row-by-row approach, so I would strongly suggest moving outside of SSRS and pursue alternative solutions.

Comment: I'd read that post and really helpfully forgotten to include it in my question. I'll wait a few more days to see if there are any other suggestions and if not I'll happily mark this as the answer for you.

Comment: @Equalsk thank you, very much appreciated. I am keeping tabs on this topic as I've faced similar issues and, in the end, reverted to solutions outside of SSRS - developing a small library of CLR routines for SQL Server for example.

Answer (score 1):

Although I've accepted the other answer due to it being clear and helpful I didn't use that solution in the end (I was too stupid to understand it) and went for something else that works.

Disclaimer: This is a horrible hack. It works absolutely great in my scenario so I though I'd share in case it was useful to somebody else. There are many pitfalls here which could most likely be worked around given time.

I ended up following the advice in the comment given by Steven White and looking into [LookupSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ee240819.aspx). This function allows you to query a dataset to return matching rows and a **single column of data**.

It looks like this:

```
LookupSet(Fields!ComparisonField.Value,   // The value to search for, e.g '001'.
          Fields!MatchField.Value,        // The column to match on in the target dataset.
          Fields!MyColumn.Value,          // The column that will be returned.
          "MyDataSet")                    // The dataset to search.
```

This returns a string array representing the returned values.

So far so good, but I needed ALL columns and rows. This is where the dirty hack appears in the form of string concatenation:

```
LookupSet(0,                             // Dummy ID 0.
          0,                             // Matches the dummy ID 0 so all rows are returned.
          Fields!Column1.Value + "[^]"   // I concatenate all of the values into
        + Fields!Column2.Value + "[^]"   // one string with the separator [^]
        + Fields!.Column3.Value,         // so I can split them later.
          "MyDataSet")                   // The dataset to query
```

I can now pass this to my custom assembly:

```
=MyAssemblyNamespace.Class.Method(LookupSet(0,0,Fields!Column1.Value..., "MyDataSet"), other, parameters, here)
```

Now in my C# method I have a generic object which after some reflection is actually an array of strings.

Cast to something useful:

```
var stringList = ((IEnumerable)MyDataSetObject).Cast<string>().ToList();
```

Split it:

```
foreach (var item in stringList)
{
    var columns = item.Split(new[] { "[^]" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    // columns is a string[] which holds each column value for the current row
    // So columns[0] is the value for column 1 in this row
    // In my case I pushed the values to a DataTable row each time and built a datatable 
    // which when finished represented my dataset in full with all rows and columns.
}
```

I hope this makes sense to anyone trying to achieve a similar result.

Comment: hack or not, it's a working solution which has offered some assistance to a similar issue I am facing. Nice work.

Comment: Thanks. If you do need any more information then feel free to message me here. I've been rather sparse with the details as my dominant hand is damaged and typing is a massive pain. Good luck with your project!